# Why can't I send multiple requests in parallel using rust tonic?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-async-std

I implemented the tonic [helloworld](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/helloworld-tutorial.md) tutorial. I then tried to change the client code so that I could send multiple requests before awaiting any.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let num_requests = 10;
    let mut client = GreeterClient::connect("http://[::1]:50051").await?;

    let mut responses = Vec::with_capacity(num_requests);
    for _ in 0..num_requests {
        let request = tonic::Request::new(HelloRequest {
            name: "Tonic".into(),
        });

        responses.push(client.say_hello(request));
    }
    for resp in responses {
        assert!(resp.await.is_ok());
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

This results in a compilation error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `client` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/client.rs:19:24
   |
19 |         responses.push(client.say_hello(request));
   |                        ^^^^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
```

Does that mean 'client.say_hello()' returns a type which still references client, and therefore I can't make another call to 'say_hello', which itself requires '&mut self'? Is there a way to continue to make requests before calling to 'await'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Tonic documentation](https://docs.rs/tonic/0.4.0/tonic/transport/struct.Channel.html#multiplexing-requests):

> Sending a request on a channel requires a `&mut self` and thus can only send one request in flight. This is intentional and is required to follow the `Service` contract from the `tower` library which this channel implementation is built on top of.
> ...
> To work around this and to ease the use of the channel, `Channel` provides a `Clone` implementation that is *cheap*. This is because at the very top level the channel is backed by a `tower_buffer::Buffer` which runs the connection in a background task and provides a `mpsc` channel interface. Due to this cloning the `Channel` type is cheap and encouraged.

Therefore, you can clone the client for each concurrent request you make. This eliminates the possibility of a single client being mutably borrowed more than once at any given time, so the borrow checker is appeased.

```rust
let num_requests = 10;
let client = GreeterClient::connect("http://[::1]:50051").await?;

let mut responses = Vec::with_capacity(num_requests);

for _ in 0..num_requests {
    let mut client = client.clone();

    let request = tonic::Request::new(HelloRequest {
        name: "Tonic".into(),
    });

    responses.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
        client.say_hello(request).await
    }));
}

for resp in responses {
    let resp = resp.await;
    assert!(resp.is_ok());
    assert!(resp.unwrap().is_ok());
}
```